# Pass the value of a variable to a command as if it were stored in a file

Tags: bash

I am interested in counting the number of lines in the output of `ps` command which I can do with

```
echo "$(ps | wc -l)"
```

However, I now have the output of `ps` command stored in a variable by doing `X="$(ps)"`. How do I pass `X`  to `wc -l` command without using a pipe? I tried `$(wc -l < "$X")` but it didn't work. I read the man page for `wc` and it takes a file as an argument. So I guess another way to frame the question would be - How do I treat value of a variable as a file to pass as an argument to a command in bash script?

I am fairly new to bash scripting and keywords I tried to search with didn't give clear answer to my questions.

Comment: I should edit my question. I’m looking to do it without a pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
echo "$X" | wc -l
```

or

```
wc -l <<< "$X"
```

Comment: Thanks! Accepting for the second option.

Comment: @ethelion The second option is generally cleaner, but is not as portable. If your script runs under a shell other than bash, it may not work. So make sure your script starts with an explicit bash shebang (like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), and don't override it by running the script with something like `sh scriptname`.