# Bash script to test status of site

Tags: bash

I have a script for testing the status of a site, to then run a command if it is offline. However, I've since realised because the site is proxied through Cloudflare, it always shows the `200` status, even if the site is offline. So I need to come up with another approach. I tried testing the site using `curl` and `HEAD`. Both get wrong response (from Cloudflare).

What I have found is that HTTPie command gets the response I need. Although only when I use the `-h` option (I have no idea why that makes a difference, since visually the output looks identical to when I don't use `-h`).

Assuming this is an okay way to go about reaching my aim ... I'd like to know how I can test if a certain string appears more than 0 times.

The string is `location: https:///` (with three forward slashes).

The command I use to get the header info from the actual site (and not simply from what Cloudflare is dishing up) is, `http -h https://example.com/`.

I am able to test for the string using, `http -h https://example.com | grep -c 'location: https:///'`. This will output `1` when the string exists.

What I now want to do is run a command if the output is `1`. But this is where I need help. My bash skills are minimal, and I am going about it the wrong way. What I came up with (which doesn't work) is:

```
#!/bin/bash
STR=$(http -h https://example.com/)

if (( $(grep -c 'location: https:///' $STR) != 1 )); then
        echo "Site is UP"
        exit
else
        echo "Site is DOWN"
        
        sudo wo clean --all && sudo wo stack reload --all
fi
```

Please explain to me why it's not working, and how to do this correctly.

Thank you.

ADDITIONS:

What the script is testing for is an odd situation in which the site suddenly starts redirecting to, literally, `https:///`. This obviously causes the site to be down. Safari, for instance, takes this as a redirection to `localhost`. Chrome simply spits the dummy with a redirect error, `ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT`.

When this is occurring, the headers from the site are:

```
HTTP/2 301
server: nginx
date: Thu, 12 May 2022 10:19:58 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
location: https:///
x-redirect-by: WordPress
x-powered-by: WordOps
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: no-referrer, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
x-download-options: noopen
x-srcache-fetch-status: HIT
x-srcache-store-status: BYPASS
```

I choose to test for the string `location: https:///` since that's the most specific (and unique) to this issue. Could also test for `HTTP/2 301`.

The intention of the script is to remedy the problem when it occurs, as a temporary solution whilst I figure out what's causing Wordpress to generate such an odd redirect. Also in case it happens whilst I am not at work, or sleeping. :-) I will have a cron job running the script every 5 mins, so at least the site is never down for longer than that.

Comment: `grep` takes filenames as arguments (i.e. the names of files to search), not raw data. See ["Pass the value of a variable to a command as if it were stored in a file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875336) for how to do this correctly. Also, don't bother using `grep -c` and then checking the number of matches, just use `grep -q` and check its exit status; see ["How to grep and then fail an if-statement on specific output from grep?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227428)

Answer (score 1):

`grep` reads a file, not a string. Also, [you need to quote strings,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) especially if they might contain whitespace or shell metacharacters.

More tantentially, `grep -q` is the usual way to check if a string exists at least once. Perhaps see also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

I can see no reason to save the string in a variable which you only examine once; though if you want to (for debugging reasons etc) probably avoid upper case variables. See also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

The parts which should happen unconditionally should be outside the condition, rather than repeated in both branches.

Nothing here is Bash-specific, so I changed the shebang to use `sh` instead, which is more portable and sometimes faster. Perhaps see also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

```
#!/bin/sh

if http -h https://example.com/ | grep -q 'location: https:///' 
then
    echo "Site is UP"
else
    echo "Site is DOWN"        
fi

sudo wo clean --all && sudo wo stack reload --all
```

For basic diagnostics, probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Regarding, `http -h https://example.com/ | grep -q 'location: https:///'` it's hard for me to test this on the command line, as it gives no output either way. Is there something I can add to it for testing purposes, so it has output telling me whether the string was found or not?

Comment: Also, the `wo ... ` command wasn't meant to be in both conditions. I've corrected the code I had in my example. RE: "The parts which should happen unconditionally should be outside the condition, rather than repeated in both branches."

Comment: I've tested the script, and it seems to go to "site is down" under all circumstances. Whether the string exists or not.

Comment: You can remove the `-q` flag to see what is being matched. The exit code from `grep` will always be available in `$?` for inspection (I have a `PS1` prompt which routinely includes the exit status of the latest executed command).

Comment: Without access to the actual URL there is no way for us to test this either. I am somewhat skeptical that checking for three slashes in the Location: header is a reliable indicator of "upness" but we only have your word to go on.

Comment: I would expect most web servers to put the Location: header in proper case; perhaps the problem is as simple as that.

Comment: Also, your question says `redirect:` in one place but `location:` in another. If you meant `redirect:` then obviously put that instead.

Comment: It should have said `location` not `redirect`. Corrected now. I've also added some additional explanation. I can confirm the string is in lowercase. Providing the actual URL won't be useful, because when the issue is occurring, the site goes down, and I need to get it back up ASAP. I hope this helps clarify the concerns you've raised. — I'll look into how I can get my prompt to display the exit codes. Thanks for that tip.

Comment: I created a fresh Ubuntu Docker instance and installed `httpie` and `netcat`. I'm getting "unknown protocol error" from `http -h` for the headers you provided. `http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', UnknownProtocol('HTTP/2')) while doing GET request to URL: http://localhost:8888/` Of course the `grep` (or anything else) on the result will not work then because it does not provide any output at all.

Comment: Thanks for going to such lengths to test it out. The headers I provided are exactly what `http -h` output (when site is down), and different set of headers when site is up. I simply copy / pasted them from my terminal after running that command. I should add, the reason I decided to assign the output to a string was mostly so I could output it in an `echo` for debug purposes. It for sure outputs what the sample I added to my question.

Comment: Which platform are you on? The documentation I'm looking at says `http -h` should just display the help message.

Comment: `http -h https://url/ | tee /dev/stderr | grep` would let you see what's being piped to `grep`

Comment: `curl -i https://example.com` also produced the same output. But I ran into an issue with trying to work with the output (I forget what ... but it lead me to using http (httpie) ... where I again ran into an issue ... but then `http -h` did the trick. I'm on Ubuntu 20.0.4.  `-h` was to `Print only the response headers`. I have no idea why that made a difference in my ability to grep it, etc. From httpie help ... `--headers, -h          Print only the response headers. Shortcut for --print=h.`

Comment: Okay. I see why I used `http -h`. Without it, I get more than just the headers ... so that simply kept the output limited to what I actually needed to work with.

Comment: My Docker image is Ubuntu 20.04 and the package I installed was named `httpie`. I can't repro with the details you have provided. (The `-h` option appears to work as you describe, as such.)

Comment: Sounds like we're using the same environment then. If `-h` doesn't work on your instance, try `--headers`, which is what my system indicates it's an abbreviation of. Or even `--print=h`

Comment: It does work, but the headers you provided cause the client to print an error and no output.